# Time waste of execv() and fork()

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, multiprocessing, fork

I am currently learning about `fork()` and `execv()` and I had a question regarding the efficiency of the combination.

I was shown the following standard code:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid < 0){
    //handle fork error
}
else if (pid == 0){
    execv("son_prog", argv_son);
//do father code
```

I know that `fork()` clones the entire process (copying the entire heap, etc) and that `execv()` replaces the current address space with that of the new program. With this in mind, doesn't it make it very inefficient to use this combination? We are copying the entire address space of a process and then immediately overwrite it.

**So my question:**
What is the advantage that is achieved by using this combo (instead of some other solution) that makes people still use this, even though we have waste?

Comment: It was very long ago that systems actually copied everything at once. I suggest you learn about [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> What is the advantage that is achieved by using this combo (instead of some other solution) that makes people still use this even though we have waste?

You have to create a new process somehow.  There are very few ways for a userspace program to accomplish that.  POSIX used to have `vfork()` alognside `fork()`, and some systems may have their own mechanisms, such as Linux-specific `clone()`, but since 2008, POSIX specifies only `fork()` and the `posix_spawn()` family.  The `fork` + `exec` route is more traditional, is well understood, and has few drawbacks (see below).  The `posix_spawn` family is designed as a *special purpose* substitute for use in contexts that present difficulties for `fork()`; you can find details in the "Rationale" section of [its specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).

This excerpt from the Linux man page for `vfork()` may be illuminating:

> **Under Linux, `fork`(2) is implemented using copy-on-write  pages,  so  the  only  penalty  incurred  by `fork`(2) is the time and memory required to duplicate the parent’s page tables, and to create a unique task structure for the child**.  However, in the bad old days a `fork`(2) would require making a complete copy of the caller’s data space, often needlessly, since usually immediately afterwards an `exec`(3) is done.  Thus, for greater efficiency, BSD introduced the `vfork`() system call, which did not fully copy the address space of the parent process, but borrowed the parent’s memory and thread of control until a call to `execve`(2) or an exit occurred.  The parent process was suspended while the child was using its  resources.  The use of `vfork`() was tricky: for example, not modifying data in the parent process depended on knowing which variables are held in a register.

(Emphasis added)

Thus, your concern about waste is not well-founded for modern systems (not limited to Linux), but it was indeed an issue historically, and there were indeed mechanisms designed to avoid it.  These days, most of those mechanisms are obsolete.

Comment: POSIX has `posix_spawn` too nowadays.

Comment: Thanks, @hvd, I obviously had overlooked posix_spawn.  I have updated the answer to account for it.

Comment: Isn't clone with CLONE_VM followed by exec more efficient?

Comment: @immibis: Yeah, but isn't that vfork()?

Comment: @immibis, `clone()` is Linux-specific.  Moreover, since the `CLONE_VM` flag results in parent and child actually running in the same memory space, I don't think it is advisable for either to call any of the exec-family functions.

Comment: Modern concerns should be about correct behavior. Why do we program like our computers are still PDP11s ?

Comment: posix_spawn is a good way into the future. Because the problem is always concurrency.

Answer (score 26):

Another answer states:

> However, in the bad old days a fork(2) would require making a complete copy of the caller’s data space, often needlessly, since usually immediately afterwards an exec(3) is done.

Obviously, one person's bad old days are a lot younger than others remember.

The original UNIX systems did not have the memory for running multiple processes and they did not have an MMU for keeping several processes in physical memory ready-to-run at the same logical address space: they swapped out processes to disk that it wasn't currently running.

The fork system call was almost entirely the same as swapping out the current process to disk, except for the return value and for *not* replacing the remaining in-memory copy by swapping in another process.  Since you had to swap out the parent process anyway in order to run the child, fork+exec was not incurring any overhead.

It's true that there was a period of time when fork+exec was awkward: when there were MMUs that provided a mapping between logical and physical address space but page faults did not retain enough information that copy-on-write and a number of other virtual-memory/demand-paging schemes were feasible.

This situation was painful enough, not just for UNIX, that page fault handling of the hardware was adapted to become "replayable" pretty fast.

Comment: The information in this answer is really not getting the appreciation that it should get. Granted, it's almost more appropriate as a comment or addition to another answer, or else edited to be a full answer replicating some of the information from the other answer reference - since in its current form this answer is more of a clarification/addendum to one of the other answers. Still, +1 from me: I'm really glad to have learned this bit of historical information.

Answer (score 23):

Not any longer. There's something called `COW` (Copy On Write), only when one of the two processes (Parent/Child) tries to write to a shared data, it is copied.

**In the past:**
The `fork()` system call copied the address space of the calling process (the parent) to create a new process (the child).
The copying of the parent's address space into the child was the most expensive part of the `fork()` operation.

**Now:**
A call to `fork()` is frequently followed almost immediately by a call to `exec()` in the child process, which replaces the child's memory with a new program. This is what the the shell typically does, for example. In this case, the time spent copying the parent's address space is largely wasted, because the child process will use very little of its memory before calling `exec()`.

For this reason, later versions of Unix took advantage of virtual memory hardware to allow the parent and child to share the memory mapped into their respective address spaces until one of the processes actually modifies it. This technique is known as **copy-on-write**. To do this, on `fork()` the kernel would copy the address space mappings from the parent to the child instead of the contents of the mapped pages, and at the same time mark the now-shared pages read-only. When one of the two processes tries to write to one of these shared pages, the process takes a page fault. At this point, the Unix kernel realizes that the page was really a "virtual" or "copy-on-write" copy, and so it makes a new, private, writable copy of the page for the faulting process. In this way, the contents of individual pages aren't actually copied until they are actually written to. This optimization makes a `fork()` followed by an `exec()` in the child much cheaper: the child will probably only need to copy one page (the current page of its stack) before it calls `exec()`.

Comment: Interesting - I would assume the call to write the return value of fork is ignored (since that would always happen instantly after forking and would defeat the purpose)?

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf a process doesn't have only one page in memory. It has much more, while you may copy the page that holds the variable that you store in the return value of fork, you save many copy operations not needed by letting the son process run first so that if it calls execv you save all these copy operations.

Comment: @Dean: no, nothing's ignored - but the return value from `fork()` probably only touches a single page (if any; depending on ABI it may never leave registers).  That's small compared to the address space of a long-lived process such as an Emacs.

Comment: Yeah, it's either going to be one page of stack (which would get unshared immediately once the child starts *doing anything* anyway) or nothing at all because the return value is just in eax or whatever :)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out all those COW page faults are not at all cheap when the process has a few gigabytes of writable RAM. They're all gonna fault once even if the child has long since called `exec()`. Because the child of `fork()` is no longer allowed to allocate memory even for the single threaded case (you can thank Apple for that one), arranging to call `vfork()/exec()` instead is hardly more difficult now.

The real advantage to the `vfork()/exec()` model is you can set the child up with an arbitrary current directory, arbitrary environment variables, and arbitrary fs handles (not just `stdin/stdout/stderr`), an arbitrary signal mask, and some arbitrary shared memory (using the shared memory syscalls) without having a twenty-argument `CreateProcess()` API that gets a few more arguments every few years.

It turned out the "oops I leaked handles being opened by another thread" gaffe from the early days of threading was fixable in userspace w/o process-wide locking thanks to `/proc`. The same would not be in the giant `CreateProcess()` model without a new OS version, and convincing everybody to call the new API.

So there you have it. An accident of design ended up far better than the directly designed solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Because the child of fork() is no longer allowed to allocate memory even for the single threaded case"? Out of curiosity, why is this the case? How does this relate to Apple?

Comment: @JordanMelo: Apple started spawning background threads in libc that call malloc(). malloc() takes a lock, so if you call fork() in the child you could deadlock as there is nobody to ever free the lock in the child. Prior to Apple's change you had to be multithreaded to have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that expensive (relatively to spawning a process directly), especially with copy-on-write `fork`s like you find in Linux , and it's kind of elegant for:

1. when you really just want to fork off a clone of the current process  (I find this to be very useful for testing)
2. for when you need to do something just before loading the new executable
   (redirect filedescriptors, play with signal masks/dispositions, uids, etc.)

POSIX now has `posix_spawn` that effectively allows you to combine fork/and-exec (possibly more efficiently than `fork`+`exec`; if it is more efficient, it'll usually be implemented through some cheaper but less robust fork (`clone`/`vfork`) followed by exec), but the way it achieves #2 is through a ton of relatively messy options, which can never be as complete and powerful and clean as just allowing you to run arbitrary code just before the new process image is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

A process created by exec() et al, will inherit its file handles from the parent process (including stdin, stdout, stderr). If the parent changes these after calling fork() but before calling exec() then it can control the child's standard streams.