# New Process Creation in Operating System (Unix)

Tags: c, unix, fork

I am sorry if my question seems silly. I have a query regarding new process creation in operating system. Consider the following simple C code:

```
//hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

    {
        printf("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

When is Compiled with gcc.

```
gcc hello.c
```

now executing the executable a.out

```
./a.out
```

Now I don't understand how in this case `New Process` is created, who calls the `fork()` and `exec` system calls and `which process is duplicated` to have a.out as child process? In [this example](https://www.go4expert.com/articles/create-processes-unix-c-t24922/), parent process explicitly calls fork system call to create child process but in above hello.c code there is no fork call.

Comment: The shell calls `fork()`. It duplicates itself, then calls `execv()` to execute the command in the child process.

Comment: the shell calls `fork` to create a process for your program to run inside

Comment: This is the purpose of a shell.

Comment: If that would be necessary, how would **that** code be started? Tortoise all the way down?

Comment: @Olaf the kernel starts the first process called `init` (in linux), that has the pid = 0. The kernel is loaded by the kernel loader that is loaded by the bios. The bios looks for this at a fixed address. The bios is started by the hardware. The hardware is started by you when you press the power button. :)

Comment: @Olaf, Ofcourse I know you know all this.

Comment: You could use `getppid()` to get the `PID` of the Parrent (if it is still running).

Comment: What happens if the parents process size (in terms of page frames) is much more than the child process like in above case!! Will the unnecessary pages from the parent page frames (duplicate one) will be removed to load the entire different process pages???

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: You very much missed the point. Did you understand the citation ("Tortoise all the way down?")?

Comment: In your case, the shell itself is forking.

Comment: @Olaf, I am afraid I did not. Will look it up.

Comment: @Aimal Linux use COW (Copy On Write), so `fork()` copy only a few pages, if not only a single page.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877495/time-waste-of-execv-and-fork/39877580

Comment: Thanks @TonyTannous, let say parent process contains 10 page frames and the child process (to be executed a.out) only contains 3 page frames so OS will change only three page frames via COW operation. what about the reaming 7 page frames, will they be removed or what??

Comment: @Aimal, the parent has 10 pages, child will only copy the page table, they both will point to the same frames. When one of them tries to change by writing we duplicate. If the child process issues `execv()` then it doesn't copy anything and a new program is executed and its pages are copied to memory when needed.

Comment: Bundles of thanks @TonyTannous.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @TonyTannous, what about if executable is double clicked. in that case which process is the parent process?

Comment: Open a new question as I am not sure what to answer :) I can only guess. But it is worth being asked. Don't forget to link me with the new question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the parent process issues the `fork()` system call, creating a duplicate process having (mostly) the same properties as the original process (different process ID, for example). From there, the child process [issues one of the `exec` family system calls](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) to replace its own process image with a new one. [This is explained quite well on the Unix SE.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123457/what-happens-when-we-type-a-simple-command-on-shell)

[image]

In your case, the shell is the parent process, and the "new program" you are running is the child process which eventually calls `exec`.

Comment: what if executable is double clicked, and not invoked through bash shell?

Comment: @Aimal Then the parent application would be the file explorer or desktop manager. It still does the same thing: forks, and execs.

Comment: @Aimal No sweat. If this answers your question adequately, please mark it as "accepted" via the check mark icon.

Comment: got it @DevNull.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell will create new process for your program and it will do exec. It means parent process for your program is your shell.

> echo $$  This command will give shell process ID.

Program :

```
printf("PPID : %d, PID : %d\n", getppid(), getpid() );
```

When you are run the program you will get below output.

PPID : 19172, PID : 26388

Note :

```
  Parent process and shell process ID's are same.
```